# How to get the last insert ID in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables, `user` and `student`.
`user` is the parent table and `student` is the child table

so from the following code

```
public void adduserStudenttype(StudentAddUserModel s)
{
    using (DASEntities db = new DASEntities())
    {
        user u = new user();
        u.usersEmail = s.Email;
        u.usersPassword = s.Password;
        u.usersFname = s.Fname;
        u.usersUtype = s.UserType;
        db.user.Add(u);
        db.SaveChanges();
        
        student stud = new student();
        stud.studentID = \\ how to get the id in the user last insert
    }     
}
```

how can i get the last insert `id` from the `user` table?
`id` is the primary key in `user` table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could get it as below:

```
// I suppose that the corresponding's property name is ID.
// If it is not, you should change it correspondingly.
stud.studentID = u.ID;
```